# why am i getting No module named 'sas7bdat' for sas7bdat

Tags: sas, modulenotfounderror

After using  pip install sas7bdat and getting a Successfully installed sas7bdat-2.2.3
I still get No module named 'sas7bdat' for sas7bdat when I import sas7bdat

Comment: Is this Python I assume? You want to add your code, errors and what language you're using to this post to align with Stack Overflow guidelines. Please review this helpful post on how to post a question [ask]

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/sas7bdat/ The example has SAS7BDAT upper cased, make sure your code follows that just in case as Python is case sensitive.